# How to increase one window and make all others equal height?

Tags: vim-windows, normal-mode

I use Vim version 8.2

I have e.g. 5 windows.

I have made these of equal height by normal command

```
CTRL-W =
```

1. first question:

How to write this to be executed as :excommand in the EXcmd line?

2. second question:

I want to resize one of these windows to make it higher by e.g. 3 lines by:

```
resize +3
```

or

```
3 CTRL-W
```

and to make the other 4 windows of equal height each, now a smaller height as before.

How can I acomplish that?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd>`=` is:

```
:wincmd =
```

To resize the other windows to equal height with the exception of the current one you could do:

```
set winfixheight
wincmd =
set nowinfixheight
```

The total script being:

```
res +3
set wfh
winc =
set nowfh
```

Comment: Thanks to Vivian De Smedt:: This is a very great gain for me, the code does just what I have needed ever. I will incorporate this code in the collection of important commands. I my case as Excmd line, with bar "|" as delimiter. Very many thanks. Regarda.

Comment: You are welcome :-) Thanks for the feedback @Anton! If it solve your problem maybe could you validate the solution using the green v flag next to the voting buttons :-)